# get actioncable to work with vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, vagrantfile, actioncable

I did all the steps that are required to get action cable up and running, uncommenting cable lines, creating channels, installing redis ..etc
but it all fails because of this line

```
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer()
```

I making invalid requests to the site since I'm operating within virtualbox.
and even action cable logging isn't working

```
module ApplicationCable class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base identified_by :current_user
def connect
  puts "YOU ARE CONNECTED "
  self.current_user = find_verified_user
  logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
end

protected

def find_verified_user # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise
  if verified_user = env['warden'].user
    verified_user
  else
    reject_unauthorized_connection
  end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm pretty sure is vagrant issue but I don't know how to fix it,

here is my vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.box      = 'ubuntu/wily64'
  config.vm.hostname = 'rails-dev-box'
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5432, host: 15432
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 6379, host: 6379

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: 'bootstrap.sh', keep_color: true

  config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|
    v.memory = 1024
    v.cpus = 2
  end
end
```

bootstrap.sh just install rvm / rails/ postgres ..etc

I even turned off my firewall. I mean the meta tag is correct

```
<meta name="action-cable-url" content="/cable">
```

when I run App.cable, I get this

```
url:"ws://localhost:3000/cable" connection: {disconnected: true}
```

I have this in my route.rb

```
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

my cable.js is

```
//= require action_cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./channels

(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

}).call(this);
```

and rails console doesn't show actioncables logs

and I use rails 5 default server:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.2.5-p319), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Comment: can you detail your vagrant setup if you're sure if comes from there ? vagrantfile config how you make the requests etc

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I have included my vagrant file to the post